# Working command in a plain Powershell prompt gives Access denied in a PSSession

Tags: windows, powershell, security, powershell-remoting

This is not a question about not being able to start a PSSession, rather about apparently different access rights when in a PSSession.

#### Following set of commands work

1. Start a Powershell prompt
2. Run `cmd /c sc queryex WerSvc`

#### Following set of commands don't work

1. Start a Powershell prompt
2. Run `Enter-PSSession localhost`
3. Run `cmd /c sc queryex WerSvc`

My user has the right to execute `sc queryex` but apparantly not when in a PSSession. Does anyone have any idea where I should start checking access rights?

[image: Works in prompt, not in PSSession]

**Edit** <sub>cudo's to PetSerAl</sub>

Below the output of `whoami /all` in the standard powershell prompt and in the PSSession.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxx> whoami /all

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name          SID
================== ===============================================
corporate\xxxxxxxx S-1-5-21-3650376746-1030869643-1781887868-23610


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                 Type             SID                                             Attributes
========================================== ================ =============================================== ===============================================================
Everyone                                   Well-known group S-1-1-0                                         Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users               Alias            S-1-5-32-555                                    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON      Well-known group S-1-5-14                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                   Well-known group S-1-5-4                                         Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users           Well-known group S-1-5-11                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization             Well-known group S-1-5-15                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                      Well-known group S-1-2-0                                         Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CORPORATE\xxxxxxxx                         User             S-1-5-21-348289982-344025507-1237804090-35554   Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Authentication authority asserted identity Well-known group S-1-18-1                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CORPORATE\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_RDP       Alias            S-1-5-21-3650376746-1030869643-1781887868-21634 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Local Group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level     Label            S-1-16-8192


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                Description                    State
============================= ============================== ========
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking       Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set Disabled


USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.

Kerberos support for Dynamic Access Control on this device has been disabled.
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxx> enter-pssession localhost

[localhost]: PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents> whoami /all

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name          SID
================== ===============================================
corporate\xxxxxxxx S-1-5-21-3650376746-1030869643-1781887868-23610


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                 Type             SID                                             Attributes
========================================== ================ =============================================== ===============================================================
Everyone                                   Well-known group S-1-1-0                                         Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users               Alias            S-1-5-32-555                                    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK                       Well-known group S-1-5-2                                         Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users           Well-known group S-1-5-11                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization             Well-known group S-1-5-15                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CORPORATE\xxxxxxxx                         User             S-1-5-21-348289982-344025507-1237804090-35554   Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Authentication authority asserted identity Well-known group S-1-18-1                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CORPORATE\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_RDP       Alias            S-1-5-21-3650376746-1030869643-1781887868-21634 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Local Group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level     Label            S-1-16-8192


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                Description                    State
============================= ============================== =======
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking       Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set Enabled


USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.

Kerberos support for Dynamic Access Control on this device has been disabled.
```

Comment: show output of `whoami /all` in both cases.

Comment: @PetSerAl - I have added the output to the question. Unfortunately, no differences.

Comment: *Unfortunately, no differences.* What? In one case you do have `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` in other you do not. Now if you look into output of `sc sdshow WerSvc`, then you will see that that is the SID to which access rights is given (at least by default). You probably can use `Enter-PSSession localhost -EnableNetworkAccess` to connect to PowerShell session with interactive token.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Now this *is* embarrassing. I must have compared the output of the same command :(. Thanks for catching that!. I can't test until tomorrow, I'll let you know.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Adding `-EnableNetworkAccess` works. I fail to see the connection with the command being executed and network access :) but please post an answer so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`whoami /all` output shows that you use interactive logon to run PowerShell, while PowerShell remoting use network logon by default, when creating session. You can use `-EnableNetworkAccess` parameter to use existing interactive session instead of creating new network logon.

If you look at `WerSvc` service security descriptor (you can do so with `sc.exe sdshow WerSvc` command), than you can see that it give permissions to access service to interactive logon and not give such permissions for network logon. Thus you see difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

May it be possible, that you start a elevated Powershell and after `Enter-PSSession` you end up in a less privileged shell?

Try to check with this line:

```
[bool]$isElavated = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

Comment: TimPe - `(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)` returns `false` in the powershell prompt (both plain and pssession)